# image not recognized when install jdk-8u121-macosx-x64

Tags: java

I have installed the `jre-8u121-macosx_8.0.1210.13.dmg`

When I install my downloaded jdk(`jdk-8u121-macosx-x64`), there comes an issue:

> jdk-8u121-macosx-x64 image not recognized

[image]

---

Comment: [dmg not recognized](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3758993?tstart=0) may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the issue, I check the jdk's dmg, and find that the dmg's size only 7KB, so this dmg is a failed one.

[image]

I remenber, when I download it, it was break off some times caused by the network, I refresh to download it again.

So, I download the jdk in the oracel official site again, and it is normal now, I check the dmg's size is 234.1MB, this one can be install.